# Finitely generated Hom module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, projective-module

> Let $M, P$ be two finitely generated $A$-modules ($A$ is a commutative ring with $1$). Let also $P$ be projective. I have to prove that Hom$_A(P,M)$ is finitely generated as $A$-module.

Before to face this exercise I had to prove that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}_+$ the $A$-module Hom$_A(A^n,M)$ is finitely generated.

I proved that observing that Hom$_A(A^n,M)\cong M^n$ wich is obviously finitely generated.

Now being $P$ projective i thought to exploit exacr sequences.

If I had an exact sequence

$$0\rightarrow \mbox{Hom}_A(P,M)\rightarrow \mbox{Hom}_A(A^k,M)\rightarrow P\rightarrow 0$$

where $k$ is the number of generator of $P$, I would conlcude that

$$\mbox{Hom}_A(A^k,M)\cong P\oplus\mbox{Hom}_A(P,M)$$

and it would follow that Hom$_A(P,M)$ is finitely generated.

Unfortunately I have not been able to define the exact sequence that I stated above.

Am I on the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

We have a **splitting** short exact sequence

$$0 \to Q \to A^n \to P \to 0.$$

Apply $\operatorname{Hom}(-,M)$ to get a **splitting** short exact sequence

$$0 \to \operatorname{Hom}(P,M) \to \operatorname{Hom}(A^n,M) \to \operatorname{Hom}(Q,M) \to 0.$$

Comment: Does Hom preserve splitness?

Comment: Every functor preserves splitness. Thats the definition of a functor.

Comment: Is there a fast way to see it?

Comment: I imagine that not seeing it might be harder.

Comment: Ahahaha, ok I'll think about it.

Comment: Hmm, is splitness really preserved by all functors? Do we not have to at least assume a bit of extra structure on the target category?

Comment: To be safe, we talk about $A$-**Mod** only here.

Comment: Ok, i got it. It was easy. So can we say that a controvariant functor transforms every projective module in an injective one?

Comment: This is wrong. How do you want to conclude this?

Comment: No, I was wrong, sorry. The transformed sequence splits only when the functor is applied to all its modules.